# tinymce selector to div id only

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

With current setup tinymce selector is set to all textarea fields on my page. How can I change this to only one field using css id property?

This is my current setup

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<script>
tinymce.init({ selector: "#myid" });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
<script>
tinymce.init({ selector: "div#div1" });
</script>
```